# Authorization error in samlWebSso20 config on WebSphere Liberty with WSO2 server as Identity Provider

Tags: wso2, authorization, saml-2.0, websphere-liberty, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to achieve SSO to Websphere Liberty adminCenter console using SAML with WSO2 as Identity Provider. I have configured samlWebSso20 on liberty as per the settings mentioned here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCKRH_1.0.2/platform/sso_liberty.html

However, the authorization fails at the liberty side as I receive the following error in messages.log:

CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking com.ibm.ws.management.security.resource on /. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [Administrator].

It seems that liberty is not able to identify roles of the user. What could possibly be wrong in my configuration?

server.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
        <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
        <feature>websocket-1.1</feature>
        <feature>samlWeb-2.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
        httpPort="9080"
        httpsPort="9443" />
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
    <basicRegistry id="basic">
        <user name="admin" password="admin" />
    </basicRegistry>
    <administrator-role>
        <user-access-id> user:ws02is510/admin</user-access-id>
    </administrator-role>
    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="liberty" />
    <samlWebSso20 enabled="true" id="defaultSP" nameIDFormat="email" wantAssertionsSigned="false">
    </samlWebSso20>
    <variable name="defaultHostName" value="wasl9" />
</server>
```

Authenticated Response Token from WSO2:

```
<saml2p:Response Destination="https://wasl9:9443/ibm/saml20/defaultSP/acs"
             ID="_3a43e5d918468a66dfe72be986c6655e"
             InResponseTo="_qmj6w34tYpe67bP0QNHuFi6hjAyjEogS"
             IssueInstant="2020-03-31T12:54:42.492Z"
             Version="2.0"
             xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
             >
<saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
              xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
              >ws02is510</saml2:Issuer>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
        <Reference URI="#_3a43e5d918468a66dfe72be986c6655e">
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue>tIwEGcLKGUgicewNgegWCXirH5ma/oPYfTVeeu/eHFI=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>
    E0yABNNUvmiDaSf3pxC3K4K/wOsvcEUA5y3uWmLi1d452LskX28ak099yZz4dDqTe+CXTTR+cM0O
    gmBHPsuJLOmXjuO+UF7mAASQmL04UlU9gVyEuNYcRa37g5YFR0kzjm4iP5HWTV03xE3T0SprUahJ
QZdPy+LDBibrsF2sYy3HTel04vXzQc9h8hZJQnCMYfnS/hZXQ3mGJkfbgCIRjoDpGoHQk3gpFJlm
CgPvmkjY6+BM8rryG3Pn5F9JAoiH5j5NRbsdlvIYI334TNu21i4Se5v8dqItG3RvWwOnjlQ4j1Jy
AFP1MH6TffMhS6bEg2is9Kmyl9VVIcsDfpIIMg==

</SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDVzCCAj+gAwIBAgIEKGtdMzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBcMQswCQYDVQQGEwJQSzEQMA4GA1UE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</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:Assertion ID="_a29d997b5f5eec9a7de1dea1e0a79391"
                     IssueInstant="2020-03-31T12:54:42.492Z"
                     Version="2.0"
                     xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                     >
        <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">ws02is510</saml2:Issuer>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                <Reference URI="#_a29d997b5f5eec9a7de1dea1e0a79391">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                    <DigestValue>M6gJ6nCtngEQZvCwaFJj9mClOhtb6hWymvAHunhK3YU=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>
Hm4yL/STOxHmksgQr7xFwlv1GAkgrb2bicUTqkiWF46zuZKaN9u1yOBqfEHHB0Q5R3nwUqju93Ce
RI+yCsf0MabDhsWThpTkuiWaEeKa1xhdMqgGIYs2G4yMYbQevrxhxe8gjPKp29A3zNLnYmDiiqHn
DSE2qdWTu1rLj9IPp3YtP5nIZX84KbRq0GbTZf3mZWfYOVwUiemTYhArZf+fhTeKdNpt52eFf2Ef
WZRQIa69a0haor1/7Adt/TLlJSwSvKn6k20It43W48aj6w905tSOmCfx2Vdmiod7ezx+o2K37SrX
M6SYPC2jKWt5AoyZ4zjhlnYiRmF0iU31KoEOng==
</SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDVzCCAj+gAwIBAgIEKGtdMzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBcMQswCQYDVQQGEwJQSzEQMA4GA1UE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</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
        <saml2:Subject>
            <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">admin</saml2:NameID>
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_qmj6w34tYpe67bP0QNHuFi6hjAyjEogS"
                                               NotOnOrAfter="2020-03-31T12:59:42.492Z"
                                               Recipient="https://wasl9:9443/ibm/saml20/defaultSP/acs"
                                               />
            </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2020-03-31T12:54:42.492Z"
                          NotOnOrAfter="2020-03-31T12:59:42.492Z"
                          >
            <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml2:Audience>https://wasl9:9443/ibm/saml20/defaultSP</saml2:Audience>
            </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml2:Conditions>
        <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2020-03-31T12:54:42.477Z">
            <saml2:AuthnContext>
                <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml2:AuthnContext>
        </saml2:AuthnStatement>
    </saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Comment: Hope this can help you https://portal2portal.blogspot.com/2017/05/doh-websphere-liberty-profile-still.html

Comment: What I understand that this post is is not related to samlWebSso20 authentication. It is about the general direct authentication of liberty. This works for me. I get the error with I configure samlWebSso20

Comment: @PiraveenaParalogarajah It worked! the realm="ws02is510" did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: Please update the question with the answer. This may be useful for some users.

Comment: Liberty authorization is based on access-id, which has format of user:realm-name/unique-user-id. For admin security, as you have found out, it is <user-access-id> user:ws02is510/admin</user-access-id>. For normal web application, it is  <user name="admin" access-id="user:ws02is510/admin"/>

Comment: @Chunlong yes I also have the same understanding, but what's happening is that when I write <user-access-id> user:ws02is510/admin</user-access-id> under <administrator-role>, it doesn't work and I receive authorization error. However when I write <user>admin</user>, it works

Comment: Also, I need to correct that the issue hasn't been solved completely, I am only getting logged in to the adminCenter landing page, not the other apps/options inside it, for example when I click on Server Config or Explore, it again asks for username/password

Comment: can you change     <samlWebSso20 enabled="true" id="defaultSP" nameIDFormat="email" wantAssertionsSigned="false">
    </samlWebSso20>      to       <samlWebSso20 enabled="true" id="defaultSP"   disableLtpaCookie="false" nameIDFormat="email" wantAssertionsSigned="false">
    </samlWebSso20> ? Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: It worked now! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Just want to ask that I am still getting the following error in logs: SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.  Stack trace of errant attempt to set header: 
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.addHeader(SRTServletResponse.java:2168). Should I ignore it as the SSO is working fine?

Comment: you can ignore the exception. The admin center application defines an error page for  401 code, however SAML already commits response (redirect user to IdP). I will open a defect to resolve the conflict, and get rid of the annoying message.

Comment: @Chunlong Ok.. Thank you very much for your assistance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Piraveena and @Chunlong for supporting, specifically to @Chunlong for working out till end to help resolve issue completely. I have got it working now by making the following changes in WAS Liberty server.xml file:

1. Adding property realm="ws02is510" in basicRegistry tag
2. Adding admin under
3. Adding property disableLtpaCookie="false" in samlWebSso20 tag